# Is $n!$ divisible by $(n + 1)(n + 2)\cdots(n + d)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is $n!$ divisible by $(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+d)$ when $n\ge 7$ is prime and $n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+d$ form a prime gap?

Comment: If I understand the terminology, then no: $3!$ is not divisible by $4$ ($n = 3$ and $d = 1$).

Comment: What if n >= 7?

Comment: How exactly are you defining a prime gap -- is it that $n$ and $n+d+1$ are prime, so that the numbers you are multiplying are the composite numbers between them?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am defining a prime gap as the set of the d composite numbers between the primes n and n + d + 1, for example {24,25,26,27,28} between 23 and 29

Comment: What about gaps between prime powers? Then the case $3$ is covered.

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition that counter examples are a feature of small numbers is correct. Indeed, the statement $\prod_{i=1}^d(n+i) \mid n!$ is equivalent to the statement that for every prime $p$, $v_p(\prod_{i=1}^d(n+i))\le v_p(n!)$. Since the next prime after $n$ is $n+d+1$, there are no primes $p$ dividing $\prod_{i=1}^d(n+i)$ which are not dividing $n!$, hence either $p\le n$ or both valuations are $0$.

The analysis is divided into $3$, I imagine this may be optimized, but I don't find a particular reason to do so.

- The case where $p$ is small, $p=2$.
- The case where $p$ is medium: $3\le p \le c\cdot n$, for a constant to be optimized for later on.
- The case where $p$ is large: $c\cdot n\le p\le n$.

Let's begin with the second case, which is most interesting: We can assume $n$ is large enough so that by the prime number theorem, $\pi((1 + \epsilon)n) - \pi(n) > 0$. This means that $d < \epsilon\cdot n$. We shall optimize for $\epsilon$ later.

$p$ divides $(n+d)!$ as many times as: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[(n+d)/p^k]$.

Similarly, $p$ divides $n!$: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[n/p^k]$ many times.

Subtracting, $p$ divides $\prod_{i=1}^d(n+i)$: $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left([(n+d)/p^j] - [n/p^j]\right)$ many times. So the divisibility requirement translates into an equivalent statement, namely that:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left([(n+d)/p^j] - [n/p^j]\right) \le \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} [n/p^j],$$ which is equivalent to $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}[(n+d)/p^j]\le 2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}[n/p^j]$.

The left hand side is upper bounded by $(n+d)/(p-1)$. Using $d \le \epsilon\cdot n$, we get the upper bound $n\dfrac{1 + \epsilon}{p-1}$.

The right hand side is lower bounded by $2[n/p] \ge 2(n/p - 1)$, plugging back, we demonstrate the stronger statement: $(n-p) \ge (1+\epsilon)\dfrac{np}{2(p-1)}$. Assuming $p\ge 3$ so that $p/(p-1) \le 3/2$, the right hand side is upper bounded by $3(1+\epsilon)n/4$, by choosing $\epsilon$ to be as little so that this is further upper bounded by $4n/5$, we complete the analysis of this case by choosing $c < 1/5$.

For $n\ge p\ge c\cdot n$, we have $p$ dividing $n!$ at least $[n/p]\ge 1$ many times. Fixing $\epsilon < c/2$ in hindsight, $p$ divides $\prod_{i=1}^d(n+i)$ in at most one term, where it may divide it at most once when $n$ is assumed large enough so that $n < (cn)^2$.

I leave to you as an exercise to complete the analysis for $p=2$.

Hint: consider picking up an extra term for the lower bound of $\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}[n/2^k]$.

Comment: So, what is the conclusion?

Comment: This seems to prove it for $n \ge 26$, and you can then manually verify it for $7 \le n \le 25$.

Comment: Is it enough to assume that all of $n+1,\dots,n+d$ are non-primes? (i.e. no assumption that $n$ and $n+d$ be primes)

Comment: @YCor: This is trivially true: If $p<n+1$, $q>n+d$ are the next primes, then $(q-1)!|p!^2$ by the result, so $(n+d)!|n!^2$ as well.